# Angular 2 include ng2-ace package

Tags: angular, npm, ace-editor

I've been trying to get the npm package [ng2-ace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ace) working, for using the ace-editor tag on a div, but I always the the error 'Cannot find module ng2-ace'.

So this is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AceEditorDirective } from 'ng2-ace';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [AceEditorDirective],
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

And this is my app.component.ts

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/',
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',

      'brace': 'npm:brace',
      'w3c-blob': 'npm:w3c-blob',
      'buffer': 'npm:buffer-shims',
      'ng2-ace': 'npm:ng2-ace'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },

      'ng2-ace': {
        format: 'cjs',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: './index.js'
      },

      'w3c-blob': {
        format: 'cjs',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: './index.js'
      },

      'brace': {
        format: 'cjs',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: './index.js'
      },

      'buffer': {
        format: 'cjs',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: './index.js'
      },
    }
  });
})(this);
```

brace is a dependency of ng2-ace which has a dependency w3c-blob which also has the depencey buffer. 
I just started working with Angular 2 so I'm not very accustomed to the workflow.

Anyway Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Angular2 are you using?

Comment: 2.0.2 I'm guessing or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Can you check what version you have for "@angular/*" packages in your package.json file?

Comment: @Sefa Yes i have 2.0.2 on all of them though @angular/router is 3.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following steps to configure ace-editor.

**step 1**

Install packages

```
npm i brace w3c-blob buffer base64-js ieee754 --save
```

**step 2**

Create directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

import 'brace';
import 'brace/theme/monokai';
import 'brace/mode/javascript';
declare var ace: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[ace-editor]'
})
export class AceEditorDirective {
  _readOnly: any;
  _theme: any;
  _mode: any;

  editor: any;
  oldVal: any;

  @Input() set options(value) {
    this.editor.setOptions(value || {});
  }

  @Input() set readOnly(value) {
    this._readOnly = value;
    this.editor.setReadOnly(value);
  }

  @Input() set theme(value) {
    this._theme = value;
    this.editor.setTheme(`ace/theme/${value}`);
  }

  @Input() set mode(value) {
    this._mode = value;
    this.editor.getSession().setMode(`ace/mode/${value}`);
  }

  @Input() set text(value) {
    if(value === this.oldVal) return;
    this.editor.setValue(value);
    this.editor.clearSelection();
    this.editor.focus();
  }

  @Output() textChanged = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() editorRef = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    const el = elementRef.nativeElement;
    el.classList.add('editor');

    this.editor = ace.edit(el);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.editorRef.next(this.editor);
    });

    this.editor.on('change', () => {
      const newVal = this.editor.getValue();
      if(newVal === this.oldVal) return;
      if(typeof this.oldVal !== 'undefined') {
        this.textChanged.next(newVal);
      }
      this.oldVal = newVal;
    });
  }
}
```

**step 3**

Configure systemjs.config.js

```
  map: {
    ...

    'brace': 'npm:brace@0.8.0',
    'w3c-blob': 'npm:w3c-blob/index.js',
    'buffer': 'npm:buffer/index.js',
    'base64-js': 'npm:base64-js/index.js',
    'ieee754': 'npm:ieee754/index.js'   
  },
  packages: {
    ...
    brace: {
      main: './index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
```

**step 4**

Include the AceEditorDirective in `declarations` list of your module

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, AceEditorDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**[Enjoy](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZKE3AmYy4FAqlSldMWz4?p=preview)**

Comment: I got it working another more hacky way, but much more clean so i'll be using it. Thanks!

Comment: Post also your systemjs config. I tried it on local machine

Comment: Ok sorry I forgot one line, it's working now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Because `ng2-ace` missed Typescript definitions. So the Angular compiler throw an error: `'Cannot find module ng2-ace'`. I think you can create custom directive from `ng2-ace` for using in your project.

Hope this help!

Comment: but ng2-ace uses Typescript. It has it's one directive definition within the library. My problem is, that i cannot access it. I'm guessing something is wrong in the systemjs.config.js

Comment: Does it throw an error when you run the app on the browser?

Comment: @Ha_Hoang I can't run it in the browser because of the error

Comment: I'm starting it from the console. But it's output is http://pastebin.com/znGMdtTv

Comment: As I mentioned, because ng2-ace don't have typescript definition that cause the error: app/app.module.ts(13,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng2-ace'. Take a look at https://github.com/seiyria/ng2-ace/issues/1